# Why does valgrind see a memory leak here when there is none

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, polymorphism, valgrind

I have the following piece of C++ code, for the time being ignore the bad practice in actually doing this in a program.

```
#include<iostream>
//#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

class P{
    public:
    void rebase(P* self);
    virtual void print();
    virtual ~P(){} 
};
class C: public P{
    virtual void print();

};
void P::rebase(P* self){
    //memory leak is detected, but no leak actually happens
    delete self;
    self=new C();
}
void P::print(){
    cout<<"P"<<endl;
}
void C::print(){
    cout<<"C"<<endl;
}


int main(){
    P *test;
    test= new P();
    test->print();
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) test->rebase(test);//run the "leaking" code 10000 times to amplify any leak
    test->print();
    delete test;
    while (true);//blocks program from stoping so we can look at it with pmap
}
```

I sent this jenky piece of code through valgrind and it reported a memory leak in P::rebase(), but when I look at the memory usage there is no leak, why does valgrind think there is?

```
==5547== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5547==    definitely lost: 80,000 bytes in 10,000 blocks
==5547==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5547==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5547==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==5547==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5547== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==5547== 
==5547== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5547== ERROR SUMMARY: 30001 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

and I double checked with `sudo pmap -x` and there is no leak

```
total kB           13272    2956     180
```

Comment: This is important issue, because a lot of C programs I designed don't declare a memory issue in debugger but valgrind report them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do have a memory leak.  The issue with

```
void P::rebase(P* self){
    //memory leak is detected, but no leak actually happens
    delete self;
    self=new C();
}
```

Is you are passing the pointer by value.  This means the pointer from main is never reassigned the new address and you actually lose it as `self` goes out of scope when the function end.  If you use

```
void P::rebase(P*& self){
    //memory leak is detected, but no leak actually happens
    delete self;
    self=new C();
}
```

Where you pass the pointer by reference then you won't have a memory leak.

---

You also have undefined in your function since you keep calling delete on the pointer from main and calling delete on a pointer more than once, if it is not null, is undefined behavior.

Essentially your code is the same as

```
int* a = new int;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    int* b = a; // we copy the address held by a
    delete b; // uh oh we call delete on that same address again
    b = new int; // put new memory in b, this does nothing to a
} // leak here as b goes out of scope and we no longer have the address it held
```

Comment: Thank you, I made the modification and valgrind  now does not detect an error.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind is correct sort of.

```
void P::rebase(P* self){
    //memory leak is detected, but no leak actually happens
    delete self;
    self=new C();
}
```

This has two problems - it does not return the new pointer to the program
It deletes a running object.

Deleting the running object may cause the code at the end of the function to crash, because there is object referencing needed to leave the function.

The code probably should crash when test->print() is called.  I think the compiler is re-using the memory for both objects.  If you switched them round e.g.

```
 P* old = self;
 self=new C();
 delete old;
```

Then it would not work.

The non-virtual call to test will work, but is causing undefined behavior.  As the real object has been destroyed after the first call.

Answer (score -1):

Valgrind is a software and it has its own logic and based on its logic it create list of warnings if some of its condition satisfy which it considered as memory leak. It does not necessary that it is a perfect memory leak. If you think that such warnings can be ignored you can simply ignore it.

But in your case I can see a clear memory leak. You instantiated a object from class `C` and you never release the memory. That is the reason in C++ we are encouraged to use smart pointer to avoid this kind mistakes.

```
self=new C();
```

Comment: In this case though it did well as the OP is actually leaking memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes true. I have modified my answer.